# Configure Gson to change key in json

Tags: java, json, gson

I am thinking of using Gson in my web-service, but i observed that Gson returns `name of a variable in class as a key in Json format`.
E.g

```
interface Animal{

}
class Dog implements Animal{
    public String name, age;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name+"\t" + age;
    }
}
```

Json for object of Dog is as follows:

```
{"name":"Tommy","age":"12"}
```

Now, my problem is since Key(`name` and `age`) in Json are dependent on name of variable, So if my variable name changes then key also changes. Then client for this web-service has to change the code whenever a variable name changes in web-service.

So Is their any way, so that i can map every variable with a key name. For e.g mapping `name  to nameOfDog` and `age to ageOfDog`, so that json will look like

```
{"nameOfDog":"Tommy","ageOfDog":"12"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using [the `SerializedName` annotation](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

Since is has a `@Target(value=FIELD)`, it can (only) be applied to instance fields.

So:

```
@SerializedName("nameOfDog")
String name;
```

(in Jackson that would be `@JsonProperty("nameOfDog")`)